# Should I unsubscribe from events?

Tags: c#, events, subscribe, unsubscribe

I have 3 questions concerning events:

1. Should I always unsubscribe events that were subscribed?
2. What happens if I do NOT?
3. In the below examples, how would you unsubscribe from the subscribed events?

I have for example this code:

Ctor: Purpose: For database property updates

```
this.PropertyChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "FirstName": break;
        case "LastName": break;
    }
};
```

and this: Purpose: For GUI-binding wrap the model into viewmodels

```
ObservableCollection<Period> periods = _lpRepo.GetDailyLessonPlanner(data.DailyDate);
PeriodListViewModel = new ObservableCollection<PeriodViewModel>();

foreach (Period period in periods)
{
    PeriodViewModel periodViewModel = new PeriodViewModel(period,_lpRepo);
    foreach (DocumentListViewModel documentListViewModel in periodViewModel.DocumentViewModelList)
    {
        documentListViewModel.DeleteDocumentDelegate += new Action<List<Document>>(OnDeleteDocument);
        documentListViewModel.AddDocumentDelegate += new Action(OnAddDocument);
        documentListViewModel.OpenDocumentDelegate += new Action<int, string>(OnOpenDocument);
    }
    PeriodListViewModel.Add(periodViewModel);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061727/is-it-bad-to-not-unregister-event-handlers

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1) It depends. Usually it's a good idea, but there are typical cases where you don't need to. Basically, if you are sure that the subscribing object is going to outlive the event source, you ought to unsubscribe, otherwise this would create an unnecessary reference.

If however your object is subscribing to its own events, like in the following:

```
<Window Loaded="self_Loaded" ...>...</Window>
```

--then you don't have to.

2) Subscribing to an event makes additional reference to the subscribing object. So if you don't unsubscribe, your object might be kept alive by this reference, making effectively a memory leak. By unsubscribing you are removing that reference. Note that in the case of self-subscription the problem doesn't arise.

3) You can do like that:

```
this.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
...
this.PropertyChanged -= PropertyChangedHandler;
```

where

```
void PropertyChangedHandler(object o, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "FirstName": break;
        case "LastName": break;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I use your bottom code I can not compile ? I put a ";" behind the last "}" but its not compiling? AND where should I unsubscribe with your suggested code?

Comment: @Lisa: (1) what is the error message you get? (2) you should unsubscribe when you don't need the events any more. Often this is at the end of your object's lifetime. If you could tell more about the object which is going subscribing for the events, it would be easier to understand when to unsubscribe.

Comment: Check my code above I subscribe 3 events OnXXX methods. A PeriodViewModel can not be delete a DocumentListViewModel neither.

Comment: @Lisa: in this case it seems that your subscriber (object which runs the code) lives longer than individual `DocumentListViewModel`, right? If so, you don't need to unsubscribe, as the `DocumentListViewModel` will die and thus release the reference to your subscriber before you'll need to free it (the subscriber).

Comment: Your second sentence seems backwards.  Since the source keeps a reference to the subscriber, it's not a problem if the subscribing object outlives the source.  The source can still be garbage collected.

Answer (score 77):

Well, let's take the last question first. You *can't* reliably unsubscribe from an event that you've subscribed to directly with a lambda expression. You *either* need to keep a variable around with the delegate in (so you can still use a lambda expression) *or* you need to use a method group conversion instead.

Now as for whether you actually need to unsubscribe, it depends on the relationship between the event producer and the event consumer. If the event producer should live for longer than the event consumer, you *should* unsubscribe - because otherwise the producer will have a reference to the consumer, keeping it alive for longer than it should be. The event handler will also keep getting called for as long as the producer produces it.

Now in many cases that's not a problem - for example, in a form the button that raises the `Click` event is likely to live for about as long as the form on which it's created, where the handler is typically subscribed... so there's no need to unsubscribe. This is very typical for a GUI.

Likewise if you create a `WebClient` solely for the purpose of a single asynchronous request, subscribe to the relevant event and start the asynchronous request, then the `WebClient` itself will be eligible for garbage collection when the request has finished (assuming you don't keep a reference elsewhere).

Basically, you should always consider the relationship between the producer and the consumer. If the producer is going to live longer than you want the consumer to, *or* it's going to continue raising the event after you're no longer interested in it, then you should unsubscribe.

Comment: event producer = documentListViewModel ? event consumer = an OnXXX-method from above? You mean if I am going to delete a documentListViewModel there is still a reference to a OnXXX-method? Where should I unsubscribe from events in a ViewModel?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean under these terms: "event producer", "event consumer", please?

Comment: @bazsisz: The event producer is the thing that raises the event, e.g. a button saying "I was clicked". The event consumer is the thing listening to (or *subscribed* to the event) which wants to react to the event occurring.

Answer (score 8):

**You don't have to desubscribe from an event when the instance that is subscribing has the same scope as the instance that is being subscribed to.**

Lets say you are a form and you are subscribing to a control, these two together form a group. However, if you have a central class that manages forms and you have subscribed to the `Closed` event of that form, these do not form a group together and you must desubscribe once the form is closed.

Subscribing to an event makes the subscribed instance create a reference to the instance being subscribed to. This prevents garbage collection. So, when you have a central class that manages form instances, this will keep all forms in memory.

WPF is an exception because it has a weak event model where events are subscribed to using weak references and it will not hold the form in memory. However, it is still best practice to desubscribe when you are not part of the form.

Answer (score 5):

You may take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) on MSDN. Quote:

> To prevent your event handler from
>   being invoked when the event is
>   raised, simply unsubscribe from the
>   event. In order to prevent resource
>   leaks, it is important to unsubscribe
>   from events before you dispose of a
>   subscriber object. Until you
>   unsubscribe from an event, the
>   multicast delegate that underlies the
>   event in the publishing object has a
>   reference to the delegate that
>   encapsulates the subscriber's event
>   handler. As long as the publishing
>   object holds that reference, your
>   subscriber object will not be garbage
>   collected.

Answer (score 1):

**1.) Should I always desubscribe events that were subscribed?**
Usually yes. The only exception is when the object on which you subscribed isn't referenced anymore and will be garbage collected soon.

**2.) What happens if I do NOT?**
The object on which you subscribed will hold a reference to the delegate, which in turn holds a reference to its `this` pointer, and thus you'll get a memory leak.
Or if the handler was a lamda it will hold onto whatever local variables it bound, which thus won't be collected either.

Comment: I would point out that if you do not unsubscribe to the event then  your handler can be called after you are finished using the object; if the object is disposable then after the object has been disposed.  This may have impact on the handler code if it uses unmanaged resources that have been released by the dispose.