# Should I unregister from event on form closing?

Tags: c#, events

I have following code:

```
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeForm f = new SomeForm();
    this.SomeEvt += f.someFunc;
    this.AnotherEvt += f.anotherFunc;
    f.Show();
}
```

Should I *unregister* `f.someFunc` from `this.SomeEvt` and  `f.anotherFunc` from `this.AnotherEvt`?

I don't want to perform neither `f.anotherFunc` nor `someFunc` when `f` is closed

And if I should do *unregister*, then how would I do that because there no longer `SomeForm f` after ending of this function?

I'm using .Net framework 4.0 and WinForms.

Comment: Also read from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172809/should-i-unsubscribe-from-events

Comment: It depends on what do you expect to have in the case when `AnotherEvt` event is *fired*, but `f` has been *closed* (i.e. do you want to perform `f.anotherFunc` when `f` is closed)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, No, I dont want to perform `f.anotherFunc` when `f` is closed

Comment: Then add up `f.CloseForm += OnMyFormClose` and implement `OnMyFormClosed` where *unregister* the events: `this.SomeEvt -= f.someFunc; this.AnotherEvt -= f.anotherFunc;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, Thank you

Comment: I've re-opened the query since the question is actually "How should I unregister if I seem to have no access to the local variable"

Comment: Is this WinForms? Or WPF? Or WebForms? Or Silverlight? Or ...?

Comment: What happens if `SomeForm f` is closed after the form that creates it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your answer to my comment:

> ...I don't want to perform `f.anotherFunc` when `f` is closed

you should *unregister* the event, e.g. with lambda:

```
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeForm f = new SomeForm();
    this.SomeEvt += f.someFunc;
    this.AnotherEvt += f.anotherFunc;

    f.FormClosed += (ss, ee) => {
      this.SomeEvt -= f.someFunc;
      this.AnotherEvt -= f.anotherFunc;
    };

    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: I never realised the irony in registering an event to unregister another event before seeing it written in a lambda...

Comment: @Marwie: there's an irony in the very basic termine *callback function*

Comment: Given that `this` is not passed to `f.Show()`, is there a risk of `SomeForm` being closed well after the form with the `someButton_Click` event? In this case wouldn't the reference from `SomeForm` back to `this` form cause the garbage collector to fail to collect `this` form?

Comment: @Martin Brown: you're quite right, if `MainForm` (let name `this` like that) is closed it could not be collected by GC until `SomeForm` (`f`) has been closed. I don't think this delay being *that* critical; in case if *it is*, one can add one lambda more: `this.FormClosed += (ss, ee) => f.Close();`