# Subscribing to event in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When subscribing to event in a controller, is there a need to unsubscribe? would not unsubscribing cause memory leaks? Why / why not?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Process(string data)
    {
        DataProcessor.Notify += (sender, args) => 
        {
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(args);
        };

        .. // do other work

        return Json(result );
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I unsubscribe from events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172809/should-i-unsubscribe-from-events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the best and safest practice IMO is to **always** unsubscribe.

In this specific scenario, you should definitely unsubscribe, as your controller will have a shorter life than your (I guess) static `DataProcessor` class. Whenever a short lived object subscribes to a long living one, it will most likely cause memory leaks, as the long living object's event delegate list will hold a reference to your short living object.

I suggest you to unsubscribe in the controller's `Dispose` method.

If the `DataProcessor` is not a static class, but a field in your controller, you have to check the scope of that object. If it's a dedicated instance for this controller instance, than you can omit unsubscribing, because the two objects will most likely be GCd together.