# Subscribing and Unsubscribing of Events

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winform, i have added a few controls like Textbox, buttons. 
I subscribed to the textbox Changed event, teh button click event. 
The designer automatically adds the += statements i.e subsribtion of events in the 
designer.cs file.

My question is should we add the unregisterig of these events in the dispose function ? 
is it necesssary, or will there be any leak if i do not unregister. 
Or is it that .NET takes care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Refers to following link:

[Is it bad to not unregister event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061727/is-it-bad-to-not-unregister-event-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

This is not required to unregister events that is subscribed on same class.

Answer (score 0):

If your WinForm is the only one that is consuming/subscribing to it, then you dont need to worry about unsub.