# When is it necessary to manually decrement an event handler

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

There is a small event handler example at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten.aspx)

with the line:

```
myNewLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(MyOnEntryWritten);
```

Presumably this adds the triggering event to a queue to be handled. What removes the handler from the queue? Do I even need to think about this?

Comment: I changed the logic so that line is only written once rather than being inside the loop. There is no longer a need to remove the event from the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "-=" operator removes the *subscriber* from the *publisher*. Not unsubscribing is a problem when the *publisher* of the event will live longer than the *subscriber*.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172809/should-i-unsubscribe-from-events) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061727/is-it-bad-to-not-unregister-event-handlers).

Comment: So in the referenced example I would add a -= entry, otherwise identical to the += version, immediately above the Signal.Set(); line? In my case this will be part of a Windows Service that could keep running for a long time, while the handler will finish in a second or so.

Comment: @Kal: no, `myNewLog` is on a different scope so you don't have access to it inside `MyOnEntryWritten`.  It would make sense to unsubscribe after `signal.WaitOne()` (if you want to set the `AutoResetEvent` to a [signaled state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) only once).

Comment: Since I want the event to happen repeatedly, are you saying I should not set the -= at all? That kind of brings the question back full circle.